# Which is the best way to link contextually related sql tables using keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say you have a dbEngine and a schema, let's say the tables are A, B and C. B has a foreign key reference to A, and C has a foreign key reference to B. Now let's say you have to add tables into this schema, all the way until Z, with the above foreign key pattern.

Is it not more efficient to use a single table, let's call it Keys, to store a reference to contextually related tables, where each key will bring back every non null entry in every table, as opposed to using a foreign key in each associated table.

Comment: Are you suggesting using a separate table to hold all your relational keys?

Comment: I can't follow this. You should elaborate a little bit further. How about adding some sample data and a data model of what your supposed structure looks like. Also no idea what "contextually" related means.

Comment: Let me paraphrase your question, "is it more efficient to add an extra table (that would be very hard to index efficiently) to a database to manage foreign key constraints (although it probably wouldn't work with NULL values properly), then have to worry about how this handles INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs, etc., rather than just using the data in the two contextually related tables to manage foreign key constraints?".  No.

Comment: Yeah, your question is totally unclear.   No idea what this means:  "where each key will bring back every non null entry in every table"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware of reinventing SQL Server.  *Keys* are not, in and of themselves, efficient.  They don't *bring back* anything.  They *restrict* updates that would violate referential integrity.  Your other table, *Keys*, would not do that.  It fails on that basis alone.

> all the way until Z

I have designed many thousands of tables and written many thousands of queries.  Eight tables in a query is a lot.  I doubt I ever saw 16.  They tend to cluster around a few, not be "strung out" in a chain.  I don't say that 26 is unheard of, but yours is an extreme example.

Your table *does exist*, though, after a fashion, among the [system tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783(v=sql.110).aspx).  (If that link will ages out, search for *sys.tables* on msdn.microsoft.com.)  The DBMS already has long had a need to, um, relate tables.  It maintains information about their actual and permitted relationships, probably in system memory using the most efficient internal structure its engineers have been able to devise.

For a particular query, it's sometimes possible to "outsmart the system" and redo in SQL space something that's implemented more generally by the server itself.  Usually that's a mistake, though. The tables are only the tip of an iceberg of features supplied by the server that are infeasible to implement in SQL.  As a rule, it's best to use the system as intended, and leave DBMS engineering to DBMS engineers.

Comment: Thanks James. Do u know how i can find this system table? In MSSQL Server of course.

Comment: I added a link to "system tables" in my answer.  HTH.